# Issues installing CausalImpact in R

Tags: r

I am trying to install the Causal Impact package in R and get the following warnings/errors:

> install.packages("CausalImpact")
> --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
> Warning: failed to download mirrors file (cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv'); using local file 'C:/Users/nlwes/AppData/Local/Programs/R/R-4.2.0/doc/CRAN_mirrors.csv'
> Warning: unable to access index for repository https://mirror.dogado.de/cran/src/contrib:
> cannot open URL 'https://mirror.dogado.de/cran/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
> Warning: unable to access index for repository https://mirror.dogado.de/cran/bin/windows/contrib/4.2:
> cannot open URL 'https://mirror.dogado.de/cran/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/PACKAGES'
> Warning messages:
> 1: In download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) :
> URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv': status was 'SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK'
> 2: package ‘CausalImpact’ is not available for this version of R
> A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
> see the ideas at
> https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Anybody an idea how to fix the issue so I can install the package?

Comment: For whatever reason R tries to look for the repo from a local directory `C:/Users/nlwes/AppData/Local/Programs/R/R-4.2.0/doc/`. Try install.packages('CausalImpact', repos='https://cloud.r-project.org')

Comment: Thanks Otto. That worked!
Now I am getting the next error when I try to load the package:

> library(CausalImpact)
Loading required package: bsts
Error: package ‘BoomSpikeSlab’ required by ‘bsts’ could not be found

Comment: Try to install bsts by install.packages(‘bsts ', repos='cloud.r-project.org')